# Proving Jensen's discrete inequality holds with equality if and only if x1=x2=x3=...=x1 (given a twice differentiable function)

Tags: analysis

Edit. This is the last question, my monster. I kind if have some work into it now and forgot to mention the function was twice differentiable

[image][image]

Well I'm not sure if the image worked but it was just the question written down. The professor advised we "lift" some of the proofs online, as some of these are not meant to be solved creatively as an undergraduate.

This is one such problem.  I can prove if f is concave then the inequality holds, but showing it only holds
with equality when all inputs are equal is not going well.

I have 1 other question like this this and a couple that I actually have some more usable ideas to go off of.

This is for a final but I assure you we are allowed any resources we want. The style of teaching seems suprising but he seems to know what he's doing. He didn't even bother to mention we make sure we completely understand the proof but I suppose it goes without saying.

I have hours and hours of unusable rabbit holes but no starting idea worth posting on this one yet. Will add to thread if I bring one into existence.[image: enter image description here](https://i![enter image description here]

Comment: Why don't you consider the case with just two values and see what happens?

Comment: I forgot about the twice differentiable thing! I may have it, for n=2 any ways. I think I can prove concavity implies a second derrivitive less than zero. And I think I can prove extema occur only ....... Nope never mind there I go forgetting my basic calculus again back to it.

Comment: Maybe of I can show f......I'm calling it a night on this problem. Thank you for your input. I have until next Friday, but have already put over 30 hours into this final and have 3 other in class finals next week as well. I hope the thread didn't sound as if I wasn't willing to put on the work. I just thought it'd be good to make it clear I might not be at some if these problems level yet. This is for 401 introduction to analysis.

Comment: Give it a shot with just two values (and maybe even a specific function), and see how that goes; I think that will help you in understanding the general case.

Comment: Is the derivative of a convex function convex? If so I have it. so adding pictures

Comment: Nevermind this is nonsense. I don't know where my head is at. I'm a much better mathematician than I come off as on here, I've done good work in this area and in this final I'm just ..... IDK. Anyways ice already done it with the function x squared, all the way up to n variables and everything in another problem, but the algebra there doesn't suffice here as far as I see.

Comment: One point worth making is it's a lie, as a straight line is concave and convex, but now I seek to prove that the only concave function with equality without equal inputs is a line

Comment: My guess is that your professor has neglected to say "strictly concave," which would make the statement true.

Comment: It's a from s book actually but yes I believe your correct. Any ideas given twice differentiability?

Comment: Learn the lingua franca of this site, LaTeX.  Don't present marginally legible images to this forum.  Please respect its culture.

Comment: Ok will have to learn next semester sorry, guess I'm on my own. Should I delete thread?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider what happens if you look at the proof of the generalization:

$$ f \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i \right) \ge \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f(x_i) $$
given that each $\lambda_i > 0$ and $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n = 1$.  Then in the inductive step, you consider:
$$ f \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i \right) = f \left( (1-\lambda_n) \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_n} x_i + \lambda_n x_n \right) \\ \ge (1 - \lambda_n) f \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_n} x_i \right) + \lambda_n f(x_n) \\ \ge (1-\lambda_n) \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_n} f(x_i)\right) + \lambda_n f(x_n) \\ = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f(x_i).$$

Now, if you have equality between the two ends, then each inequality in this chain must be equality.  Also, the hypothesis that $f$ is strictly concave pretty much directly gives that for $n=2$, equality holds if and only if $x_1 = x_2$.  Now, if you use induction, can you see how to complete the proof that equality holds in the generalized inequality if and only if $x_1 = \cdots = x_n$?  And then, how to specialize this result to get what you wanted?

Comment: Much appreciated , got the inductive step down because of that hint. But I just can't get the basis. I get the geometric picture but translating it paper is proving difficult

Comment: Nevermind now I got it. My only problem now is I can't understand how a linear f is an exception to this. It seems this proof shows for any concave function the X's must be equal. Hmmm

Comment: Nevermind no I don't. It's late will try some more tomorrow. I've shown f(X1)+...+f(Xk)=f(X1+...+Xk) for all k < or = to n. It looks really line-ish but this is given n x's. Somehow I need to use twice differentiability or at least continuity to extend this to all points within (a,b). My goal us to prove f must be a line on (a,b) or all X's are equal